# Split string in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to split string in crystal report and display as separate line item with specific labels on each different lines
String is 100 Pcs / CASE@@5 CASE / 1 PLT@@Total 500 Pcs / PLT. I need to split and display like this Box Qty= 100 Pcs / CASE
Qty/PLT= 5 CASE / 1 PLT
Pcs/PLT= 500 Pcs / PLT

Answer (score 0):

Use the Replace() function in Crystal.
For example, replace 'CASE@@' with 'CASE Qty/PLT = '